# How do I run a jquery command after JQuery and JQuery mobile are completely initialized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

For some reason one of my Select menus in JQuery Mobile seems to initialize and then disappear.

If I use the command

```
$('[id$=status]').selectmenu();
```

and bind it to a button and press the button (so its occurring after everything has intialized) then the select menu re-initializes and everything works fine.

I know its hack-y but I would like to run this line after everything else on the page has completed initializing so it shows up automatically.

I tried adding it to $(document).ready but that seems a bit too soon.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

> `$(document).bind('pageinit')`

thats what i found on the jQuery MObile doc : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html